# Integral by residue - "dog bone"

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Let $I=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{x^2 dx}{\sqrt[3]{(1-x)(1+x)^2}}$. 
I used complex function $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{\sqrt[3]{(z-1)(z+1)^2}}$, which we can  define such that it is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$. I use a "dog bone"-contur to integrate it. I have problem with integral on the big circle :
$\lim_{R \to \infty}\int_{C_R}f(z)dz$. How to calculate it ? (I know that it should be nonzero.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the function

$$f(z) = (z-1)^{-1/3} (z+1)^{-2/3} $$

$f$ is obviously the product of two functions, each having their own branch cuts.  For example, $(z-1)^{-1/3}$ has a branch cut along $(-\infty,1]$, while $(z+1)^{-2/3}$ has a branch cut along $(-\infty,-1]$.  Note that $z+1$ never changes sign along $(-1,1)$; it is always positive and away from its branch cut.  Therefore, we can say that $\arg{(z+1)}=0$ on the lines of the dogbone.  However, we do cross the branch cut of $(z-1)^{-1/3}$, i.e., $\arg{(z-1)}=\pi$ above the real axis and $\arg{(z-1)}=-\pi$ below.

Now consider the contour integral

$$\oint_C dz \, z^2 f(z) $$

where $C$ is (1) the circle $z=R e^{i \theta}$, $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi)$, (2) a line extending from the circle at $\theta=\pi$ to the dogbone contour, (3) the dogbone, and (4) a line back to the circle at $\theta=-\pi$.  Note that the integral vanishes along the lines to the dogbone and along the small circles of the dogbone.  Thus, the contour integral is

$$i R \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} R^2 e^{i 2 \theta} \left ( R e^{i \theta}-1 \right )^{-1/3} \left ( R e^{i \theta}+1 \right )^{-2/3} + e^{-i \pi/3} \int_{-1}^1 dx \, x^2 (1-x)^{-1/3} (1+x)^{-2/3} \\ + e^{i \pi/3} \int_1^{-1} dx \, x^2 (1-x)^{-1/3} (1+x)^{-2/3}$$

Note that we defined the limits of the first integral so that no branch cut on the negative real axis is traversed. There is no branch cut for $x \gt 1$. Thus, to deal with the first integral, we may expand the roots for large $R$:

$$\left ( R e^{i \theta}-1 \right )^{-1/3} = R^{-1/3} e^{-i \theta/3} \left (1 - \frac1{R e^{i \theta}} \right )^{-1/3} = R^{-1/3} e^{-i \theta/3} \left [1+\frac1{3 R e^{i \theta}} + \frac{2}{9 R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}} + O \left ( \frac1{R^3} \right ) \right ]$$

$$\left ( R e^{i \theta}+1 \right )^{-2/3} = R^{-2/3} e^{-i 2 \theta/3} \left (1 + \frac1{R e^{i \theta}} \right )^{-1/3} = R^{-2/3} e^{-i 2 \theta/3} \left [1-\frac{2}{3 R e^{i \theta}} + \frac{5}{9 R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}} + O \left ( \frac1{R^3} \right ) \right ]$$

We may extract the dominant piece of each binomial term as above because we have not crossed a branch cut.  Thus, the integrand is

$$i R^2 e^{i 2 \theta} -  i\frac{1}{3} R e^{i \theta} + i \frac{5}{9} + O \left ( \frac1{R} \right )$$

It is important to see that all terms in the expansion vanish upon integration over $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi)$, except the constant term.  This is the so-called residue at infinity.

By Cauchy's theorem, the contour integral is zero.  Thus

$$i 2 \pi \frac{5}{9} -i 2 \sin{\frac{\pi}{3}} \int_{-1}^1 dx \, x^2 (1-x)^{-1/3} (1+x)^{-2/3} = 0$$

or

$$\int_{-1}^1 dx \, x^2 (1-x)^{-1/3} (1+x)^{-2/3} = \frac{10 \pi}{9 \sqrt{3}} $$

Comment: Is there some way of solving this by appealing to beta functions ? *Mathematica* certainly seems to point in that direction. But I don't know how to “get rid” of the $1+x$ factor.

Comment: @Lucian: I think there is, but don't hold me to it.  This way is way more interesting.  To me anyway.

Answer (score 3):

With these  types of integrals usually  what is being asked  for is to
use two  branches of  the logarithm whose  cuts cancel outside  of the
integration interval.

Suppose we seek to compute
$$Q = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt[3]{(1-x)(1+x)^2}} dx.$$

Re-write this as
$$\int_{-1}^1 z^2
\exp(-1/3\mathrm{LogA}(1-z))
\exp(-2/3\mathrm{LogB}(1+z)) dz$$
and call the function $f(z).$

We  must choose  two  branches of  the  logarithm $\mathrm{LogA}$  and
$\mathrm{LogB}$ so that the cut is on the real axis from $-1$ to $1.$
This is accomplished when $\mathrm{LogA}$  has the cut on the negative
real axis and $\mathrm{LogB}$ on the positive real axis.
The  argument   of  $\mathrm{LogA}$  is   in  $(-\pi,  \pi]$   and  of
$\mathrm{LogB}$ is in $[0,2\pi).$
With these definitions we have 
for $x\lt 1$ that $\mathrm{LogA}(1-x) = \log(1-x)$
and for $x\gt -1$ that $\mathrm{LogB}(1+x) = \log(1+x)$ 
(both just above the cut) which means the complex function agrees 
with the real one on the integration interval.

In order to be rigorous we also need to show continuity across the two
overlapping   cuts  on   $(1, \infty)$   as  shown   in   this  [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329029/). The key idea here is to note that just above $(1,\infty)$ we get the factor 
$$\exp(-1/3(-\pi i)-2/3\times 0)=\exp(1/3\pi i)$$ 
and just below we get 
$$\exp(-1/3(\pi i)-2/3(2\pi i))=\exp(-5/3\pi i)$$ and these two agree.

Suppose  the  dogbone  contour  is traversed  counterclockwise.   Then
$\mathrm{LogA}$  gives   the  real  value  just  below   the  cut  but
$\mathrm{LogB}$ contributes  a factor of $\exp(2\pi  i \times - 2/3).$
Above the  cut $\mathrm{LogA}$  again produces the  real value  but so
does $\mathrm{LogB}.$ As there are no finite poles this implies that

$$Q\times (\exp(-4/3\pi i)-1)
= - 2\pi i \times \mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty} f(z).$$

Now for the residue at infinity we use the formula
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty} h(z)
= \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} 
\left[-\frac{1}{z^2} h\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right].$$

In a neighborhood of infinity we have
$$\mathrm{LogA}(1-z) = \mathrm{LogA}(-z)
- \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{1}{q z^q}$$
and furthermore
$$\mathrm{LogB}(1+z) = \mathrm{LogB}(z)
- \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^q}{q z^q}$$

This gives
$$-\frac{1}{z^2} f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)
= -\frac{1}{z^4}
\exp(-1/3\mathrm{LogA}(-1/z))
\exp\left(1/3\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{z^q}{q}\right)
\\ \times \exp(-2/3\mathrm{LogB}(1/z))
\exp\left(2/3\sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^q \frac{z^q}{q}\right).$$

We need a careful evaluation of the product
$$\exp(-1/3\mathrm{LogA}(-1/z))\exp(-2/3\mathrm{LogB}(1/z))$$
in a neighborhood of zero.

Suppose $z= R \exp(i\theta)$ with $\theta\in[0,\pi)$
we get in the upper half plane 
($\epsilon$ might be a more fitting choice for the modulus)
$$\exp(-1/3\times(-\log R + \pi i - i\theta))
\exp(-2/3\times(-\log R + 2\pi i - i\theta))$$
which yields
$$\exp(\log R + i\theta) \exp(-5/3\pi i) =
z \exp(-5/3\pi i).$$
For the lower half plane let $\theta\in[\pi, 2\pi)$ we get
(yes this is supposed to be the same)
$$\exp(-1/3\times(-\log R + \pi i  - i\theta))
\exp(-2/3\times(-\log R + 2\pi i - i\theta))$$
which again yields
$$\exp(\log R + i\theta) \exp(-5/3\pi i) =
z \exp(-5/3\pi i).$$

Returning to the main thread we have
$$-\frac{1}{z^2} f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) =
-\frac{1}{z^4} \times z \times \exp(-5/3\pi i)
\\ \times
\exp\left(1/3\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{z^q}{q}\right)
\exp\left(2/3\sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^q \frac{z^q}{q}\right).$$

We seek
$$-[z^2] 
\exp\left(1/3\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{z^q}{q}\right)
\exp\left(2/3\sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^q \frac{z^q}{q}\right).$$

This can be extracted by direct substitution of the initial terms into
the exponential series (this is the rigorous option) or using the fact
that the two sums converge in a neighborhood of zero to
$$\log\frac{1}{1-z}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\log\frac{1}{1+z}$$
so that we can use the Newton binomial on
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^{1/3}}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{1}{(1+z)^{2/3}}.$$

Note that
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^{1/3}}
= 1+{\frac {1}{3}}z+{\frac {2}{9}}{z}^{2}+{\frac {14}{81}}{z}^{3}+O
 \left( {z}^{4} \right)$$
and
$$\frac{1}{(1+z)^{2/3}}
= 1-{\frac {2}{3}}z+{\frac {5}{9}}{z}^{2}-{\frac {40}{81}}{z}^{3}+O
 \left( {z}^{4} \right)$$

so that the desired coefficient is
$$\frac{2}{9}+\frac{5}{9} - \frac{2}{9} = \frac{5}{9}$$
for a final result of
$$-2\pi i \times -\frac{5}{9} \times
\frac{\exp(-5/3\pi i)}{\exp(-4/3\pi i)-1}
= -2\pi i \times -\frac{5}{9} \times
\frac{1/2+1/2i\sqrt{3}}{-3/2+1/2i\sqrt{3}}
\\ = \frac{10\pi\sqrt{3}}{27}
= \frac{10\pi}{9\sqrt{3}}.$$

**Remark.** It really helps to think of  the map from $z$ to $-z$ as a
$180$ degree  rotation when one  tries to visualize what  is happening
here.

**Acknowledgement.** This post relies on ideas by @RonGordon
from his initial response.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a real-analysis solution for comparison. Staring with the substitution $x\mapsto2x-1$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1\frac{x^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[3]{(1-x)(1+x)^2}}
&=\int_0^1\frac{(2x-1)^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[3]{(1-x)x^2}}\\
&=4\int_0^1x^{4/3}(1-x)^{-1/3}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&-4\int_0^1x^{1/3}(1-x)^{-1/3}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&+\int_0^1x^{-2/3}(1-x)^{-1/3}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=4\mathrm{B}\left(\tfrac73,\tfrac23\right)
-4\mathrm{B}\left(\tfrac43,\tfrac23\right)
+\mathrm{B}\left(\tfrac13,\tfrac23\right)\\
&=4\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac73\right)\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)}{\Gamma(3)}
-4\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac43\right)\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)}{\Gamma(2)}
+\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)}{\Gamma(1)}\\
&=\frac89\Gamma\left(\tfrac13\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac23\right)
-\frac43\Gamma\left(\tfrac13\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac23\right)
+\Gamma\left(\tfrac13\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac23\right)\\
&=\frac59\Gamma\left(\tfrac13\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac23\right)\\
&=\frac59\pi\csc(\pi/3)\\
&=\frac{10\sqrt3}{27}\pi
\end{align}
$$
Using [Euler's Reflection Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) proven in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216).

Answer (score 1):

Defining the integrand analytically on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$ allows us to compute two integrals which are equal by [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem); one close to $[-1,1]$ in $(5)$, and the other around a large circle in $(6)$.

For $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$, we can define
$$
\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)=\frac\pi2i+\int_i^z\left(\frac1{w+1}-\frac1{w-1}\right)\,\mathrm{d}w\tag{1}
$$
where the contour of integration avoids the real interval $[-1,1]$. This is well-defined since the difference of any two such contours circles both singularities equally and so their residues cancel.

Along the {top,bottom} of $[-1,1]$, $\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)=\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)+\{0,2\pi i\}$

We can then set
$$
\frac{z^2}{\sqrt[3]{(1-z)(1+z)^2}}=\frac{z^2}{1+z}\exp\left(\frac13\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)\right)\tag{2}
$$
Along the {top,bottom} of $[-1,1]$,
$$
\frac{z^2}{\sqrt[3]{(1-z)(1+z)^2}}=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[3]{(1-x)(1+x)^2}}\left\{1,e^{2\pi i/3}\right\}\tag{3}
$$
As $|z|\to\infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{z^2}{\sqrt[3]{(1-z)(1+z)^2}}
&=\frac{z}{\sqrt[3]{\left(1-\frac1z\right)\left(1+\frac1z\right)^2}}e^{\pi i/3}\\
&=e^{\pi i/3}\left(z-\frac13+\frac5{9z}-\frac{23}{81z^2}+\dots\right)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the residue around $[-1,1]$ is $e^{\pi i/3}\frac59$.

Using $(3)$, the integral counterclockwise around $[-1,1]$ is
$$
\oint\frac{z^2}{\sqrt[3]{(1-z)(1+z)^2}}\,\mathrm{d}z
=\left(e^{2\pi i/3}-1\right)\int_{-1}^1\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[3]{(1-x)(1+x)^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5}
$$
The integral along the circles around the singularities vanishes since the integrand has order $-\frac13$ and $-\frac23$ near the singularities.

Using $(4)$, the integral around a large counterclockwise circle is
$$
\oint\frac{z^2}{\sqrt[3]{(1-z)(1+z)^2}}\,\mathrm{d}z
=2\pi i\,e^{\pi i/3}\frac59\tag{6}
$$
Comparing $(5)$ and $(6)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[3]{(1-x)(1+x)^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac{2\pi i\,e^{\pi i/3}\frac59}{e^{2\pi i/3}-1}\\
&=\frac{5\pi}{9\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)}\\
&=\frac{10\sqrt3}{27}\pi\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$