# Integrating around a dog bone contour

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Prove that

$$\int^{1}_{0} \sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{8}$$

$$\textit{proof}$$

Consider the function

$$f(z) = \sqrt{z-z^2} = e^{\frac{1}{2}\log(z-z^2)}$$

Consider the branch cut on the x-axis
$$x(1-x)\geq 0\,\, \implies \, 0\leq x \leq 1 $$

Consider $ w= z-z^2 $ then

$$\log(w) = \log|w|+i\theta,\,\, \theta\in[0,2\pi)$$

Consider the contour

[image]
Consider the integral

$$\int_{c_0}f(z)\,dz+\int_{c_1}f(z)\,dz+\int^{1-\epsilon}_{\epsilon} e^{\frac{1}{2}\log|x-x^2|}\,dx-\int^{1-\epsilon}_{\epsilon} e^{\frac{1}{2}\log|x-x^2| +\pi i}\,dx = 2\pi i \mathrm{Res}(f,\infty)$$

Consider the Laurent expansion of

$$\sqrt{z-z^2} =i \sqrt{z^2} \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z}}= iz\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{1}{2} \choose k} \left(-\frac{1}{z} \right)^k$$

Hence we deuce that

$$ \mathrm{Res}(f,\infty) = -\frac{i}{8}$$

That implies

$$\int_{c_0}f(z)\,dz+\int_{c_1}f(z)\,dz+2\int^{1-\epsilon}_{\epsilon} \sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Considering integrals the contours around $c_0$ and $c_1$ go to zero . Finally we get

$$\int^{1}_{0} \sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{8}$$

---

### Question

I have my concerns about the expansion at infinity

$$\sqrt{z-z^2} =i \sqrt{z^2} \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z}}= iz\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{1}{2} \choose k} \left(-\frac{1}{z} \right)^k$$

First I am assuming that $\sqrt{z^2} = z$ which seems to be wrong on the chosen branch cut. Also it is wrong to assume that $\sqrt{zw} = \sqrt{z}\sqrt{w}$.

Comment: You can define the branch cuts of the two square roots $\sqrt{z}$ and $\sqrt{1-z}$ separately. In this case you should choose the negative real axis for $\sqrt{z}$ and $(-\infty,1]$ for $\sqrt{1-z}$. In the product you end up with a branch cut between $0$ and $1$ while on the negative real axis the two branch cuts effectively cancel each other out. This means that on $\mathbb{C}\[0,1]$ the function is analytic, and the residue at infinity can be computed without problems.

Comment: $\sqrt{z^2}=|z|$.

Comment: @CountIblis, I appreciate your help but my interest is not solving using another approach. I want to understand what i did wrong and how to resolve it?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki What are you thinking?  $z\in \mathbb{C}$ here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a conceptual error in the OP.

Note that if $w=z(1-z)$, then the condition $\arg(w)\in[0,2\pi)$ restricts the domain of the complex $z$ plane to a half space.

To see this, we write $z=|z|e^{i\arg(z)}$ and $1-z=|1-z|e^{i\arg(1-z)}$ so that $w=|z||1-z|e^{i\left(\arg(z)+\arg(1-z)\right)}$.

Inasmuch as $\arg(z)+\arg(1-z)$ spans a range of $4\pi$ in the complex $z$-plane, then $\arg(w)$ does likewise.

---

To address the concerns in the OP in detail, we begin with a short primer.

> **PRIMER:**

The complex logarithm $\log(z)$ is defined for $z\ne 0$ as

$$\log(z)=\log(|z|)+i\arg(z) \tag 1$$

It is easy to show that the complex logarithm satisfies

$$\log(z_1z_2)=\log(z_1)+\log(z_2) \tag 2$$

which means that any value of $\log(z_1z_2)$ can be expressed as the sum of some value of $\log(z_1)$ and some value of $\log(z_2)$.

To see that $(2)$ is true, we simply note that $\log(|z_1||z_2|)=\log(|z_1|)+\log(z_2)$ and $\arg(z_1z_2)=\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2)$.

---

> **NOTE:**  The relationship in $(2)$ is not generally satisfied when the logarithm is restricted on, say, the principal branch for which $\arg(z)=\text{Arg}(z)$, where $-\pi<\text{Arg}\le \pi$.

---

Using $(2)$, we can write for $z\ne0$, $z\ne 1$

$$\begin{align}
f(z)&=\sqrt{z(1-z)}\\\\
&=e^{\frac12 \log(z(1-z))}\\\\
&=e^{\frac12 \left(\log(z)+\log(1-z)\right)}\\\\
&=e^{\frac12\log(z)}e^{\frac12\log(1-z)}\\\\
&=\sqrt{z}\sqrt{1-z}
\end{align}$$

---

> **SELECTING A BRANCH OF $\displaystyle \sqrt{z(1-z)}$**

To obtain a specific branch of $\sqrt{z(1-z)}$, we can use a branch of $\sqrt{z}$ and another branch of $\sqrt{1-z}$.

If we select the branches for $\sqrt{z}$ and $\sqrt{1-z}$ to be such that $-\pi<\arg(z)\le \pi$ and $0<\arg(1-z)\le 2\pi$, then the branch of $\sqrt{z(1-z)}$ is such that

$$\sqrt{z(1-z)}=\sqrt{|z||1-z|}e^{i\frac12 (\arg(z)+\arg(1-z))}$$

with $-\pi<\arg(z)+\arg(1-z)\le 3\pi$.

With this choice, it is straightforward to show that $\sqrt{z(1-z)}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,1]$.

---

> **EVALUATING THE INTEGRAL**

Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C \sqrt{z(1-z)}\,dz&=\int_0^1 \sqrt{x(1-x)}e^{i(0+2\pi)/2}\,dx+\int_1^0\sqrt{x(1-x)}e^{i(0+0)}\,dx\\\\
&=-2\int_0^1 \sqrt{x(1-x)}\,dx \tag 3
\end{align}$$

---

> **NOTE:**  We bypassed consideration of the contributions to the integral from the circular deformations around the branch points since their contributions vansish in the limit as the radii go to zero.

---

Using Cauchy's Integral Theorem, the value of the integral $\oint_C \sqrt{z(1-z)}\,dz$ is unaltered by deforming $C$ into a circular contour, centered at the origin, of radius, $R>1$.  Hence, exploiting the analyticity of $\sqrt{z(1-z)}$ for $R>1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C \sqrt{z(1-z)}\,dz&=\oint_{R>1}\sqrt{z(1-z)}\,dz\\\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sqrt{Re^{i\phi}(1-Re^{i\phi})}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(iRe^{i\phi}\right)^2 \left(1-\frac{1}{Re^{i\phi}}\right)^{1/2}\,d\phi\\\\
&=-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(iRe^{i\phi}\right)^2 \left(1-\frac{1/2}{Re^{i\phi}}-\frac{1/8}{(Re^{i\phi})^2}-\frac{1/16}{(Re^{i\phi})^3}+O\left(\frac1{(Re^{i\phi})^4}\right)\right)\,d\phi\\\\
&\to -\frac{\pi}{4}\,\,\text{as}\,\,R\to \infty \tag 4
\end{align}$$

Finally, putting together $(3)$ and $(4)$ yields

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{x(1-x)}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{8}$$

as expected.

---

> **NOTE:**  The expansion leading to $(4)$ is correct given the chosen branches of $\sqrt{z}$ and $\sqrt{1-z}$.  Then,

> $$\begin{align}
> \sqrt{z(1-z)}&=\sqrt{-z^2\left(1-\frac1z\right)}\\\\
> &=e^{\frac12\log(-z^2)+\frac12\log\left(1-\frac1z\right)}\\\\
> &=iz \sqrt{1-\frac1z}
> \end{align}$$

> where we used $\log(-1)=i\pi$ and $\log(z^2)=2\log(z)$.  Then, upon expanding $\sqrt{1-\frac1z}$ in its Laurent series in the annulus $1<z<\infty$, and setting $z=Re^{i\phi}$, we obtain the expansion used to arrive at $(4)$.

Comment: Hey Mark, I appreciate the effort. I still have some confusion you are saying that I have restricted the value of the argument but I know that any complex number argument should be restricted to a period of length $2\pi$ in order to make it single-valued.

Comment: Zaid, I understand.  In this case, we are mapping the $z$-plane to the $w$ plane.  And we can see that $w$ gets covered twice.  This is no different from the mapping of $w=z^2$ for which the upper half $z$-plane maps into the entire $w$ plane and the lower half $z$-plane does likewise.  We really need $\sqrt{z(1-z)}$ to be single valued by selecting a branch- and it is single valued given the chosen branches for $\sqrt{z}$ and $\sqrt{1-z}$. Its argument is on the interval $(-\pi/2,3\pi/2]$.

Comment: By way of enrichment I present a computation where only invertible logarithms of positive real numbers are used once the two branches for the integrand have been selected, consult my post below. This is computation-intensive but it produces the correct value.

Comment: Hey Mark , thanks. I marked your answer as accepted because of the thorough explanation.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai Zaid, you're certainly welcome.  It was my pleasure.  And I really do hope that it helped resolve your concerns.  -Mark

Comment: I believe you dropped a minus sign in your calculation of (4), specifically from the line before last to the last line. I think this is rectified by when comparing lines (3) and (4) that (3) and (4) ought to sum to zero. Also, I don't believe there is a need to send R to infinity, since the angular integral vanishes for all except your term of interest.

Comment: @user196574 Indeed.  And nice catch.  I've edited accordingly.  Much appreciate your note.

Comment: In your "NOTE: The expansion leading to (4)...", can you elaborate where the choice of branch comes in?  (I think I'm confused about when to use log rather than Log when 'branch chasing')  THX!

Answer (score 2):

We    may    use    the     method    from    the    following    [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2102458/)     for    the
residue at infinity. The  introduction and the continuity argument can
be copied verbatim and will not be repeated here. We use

$$f(z) = \exp(1/2\times \mathrm{LogA}(z))
\exp(1/2\times \mathrm{LogB}(1-z))$$

with the  two logarithms defined as  in the linked-to  post. Note that
this is not the choice  Mathematica or Maple makes, but consistency is
sufficient here and we can re-use a vetted computation.

The difference is that we have $f(z)\sim  z$ at infinity so we need to
determine the  coefficients on $z,$  the constant coefficient  and the
one on $1/z.$ There was less work at the linked-to computation because
the function was $\sim 1/z$ at infinity.

We use $f(z)/z^2$ for the first  one and put $z = R\exp(i\theta).$ Now
the modulus of $\mathrm{LogA}(z)$ is  $\log R.$ We get for the modulus
of $\mathrm{LogB}(1-z)$

$$\log\sqrt{(1-R\cos(\theta))^2 + R^2\sin(\theta)^2}
\\ = \log\sqrt{1-2R\cos(\theta) + R^2}.$$

We are manipulating logarithms of positive real numbers using the real
logarithm and may continue with

$$\log R + \log\sqrt{1-2\cos(\theta)/R+1/R^2}.$$

Using the  leading term  and the method  from the link  we immediately
obtain  $f(z)   \sim  -iz.$  For  the  constant   coefficient  we  use
$(f(z)+iz)/z.$ We have

$$\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\log\sqrt{1-2\cos(\theta)/R+1/R^2}\right)
= \sqrt[4]{1-2\cos(\theta)/R+1/R^2}
\\ = 1 - \frac{1}{4} (2\cos(\theta)/R-1/R^2)
- \frac{3}{32} (2\cos(\theta)/R-1/R^2)^2 -\cdots
\\ = 1 - \frac{1}{2}\cos(\theta)\frac{1}{R}
+ \left(1/4 - \frac{3}{8}\cos(\theta)^2\right)\frac{1}{R^2}
- \cdots$$

We also have

$$\arctan\left(\frac{-R\sin(\theta)}{1-R\cos(\theta)}\right)
= \arctan\left(\frac{-\sin(\theta)}{1/R-\cos(\theta)}\right)
\\ = \theta + \sin(\theta)\frac{1}{R} + 
\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\frac{1}{R^2} + \cdots$$

so that  (this actually holds  everywhere as long as  $\theta$ matches
the range of $\arg\mathrm{LogB}$)

$$\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}i\arg\mathrm{LogB(1-z)}\right)
\\ = \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}i\theta\right)
\left(1 + \frac{1}{2}i\sin(\theta)\frac{1}{R} + 
\frac{1}{2}i\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\frac{1}{R^2} -
\frac{1}{8} \sin(\theta)^2\frac{1}{R^2} + \cdots\right).$$

Adding in $iz$ cancels the contribution  from the first terms of these
two  expansions.  We  get  from  the second  term  and collecting  the
contributions from the lower and upper half plane

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{R\exp(i\theta)}
\exp(\log R) \exp(i\theta+\pi i/2)
\\ \times \left(\frac{1}{2}i\sin(\theta)\frac{1}{R}
-\frac{1}{2}\cos(\theta)\frac{1}{R}\right)
Ri\exp(i\theta)
\; d\theta
\\ = \int_0^{2\pi}
\exp(\log R) \exp(i\theta+\pi i/2) i
\left(-\frac{1}{2}\exp(-i\theta)\right) \frac{1}{R}
\; d\theta
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{2\pi}
\exp(i\theta)\exp(-i\theta)
\; d\theta = \pi.$$

for a residue of $-(\pi)/(2\pi i)  = i/2.$ This establishes $f(z) \sim
-iz + i/2.$ We  integrate $f(z) + iz - i/2$ to  get the coefficient on
$1/z$, obtaining

$$\int_0^{2\pi}
\exp(\log R) \exp(i\theta+\pi i/2)
\\ \times \frac{1}{R^2} \left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{3}{8}\cos(\theta)^2
+ \frac{1}{2} i\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)
- \frac{1}{8} \sin(\theta)^2
-\frac{1}{4}i\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\right)
\\ \times Ri\exp(i\theta)
\; d\theta$$

The inner term is

$$\frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{4}\cos(\theta)^2 + \frac{1}{8}i\sin(2\theta)
= - \frac{1}{8}\cos(2\theta) + \frac{1}{8}i\sin(2\theta)
= - \frac{1}{8}\exp(-2i\theta).$$

which leaves for the integral

$$\frac{1}{8} \int_0^{2\pi} \exp(2i\theta)\exp(-2i\theta) \; d\theta
= \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

We get the residue $-(\pi/4)/(2\pi i) = i/8.$
We have established that at infinity,

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{ f(z) \sim
-iz + \frac{1}{2} i + \frac{1}{8} i \frac{1}{z}}$$

and hence $\mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty} f(z) = \frac{1}{8} i.$ Taking  into
account  that the  contour used  with this  branch produces  twice the
value of the integral we obtain

$$\frac{1}{2} \times -2\pi i \times \frac{1}{8} i$$

which is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{ \frac{\pi}{8}.}$$

Answer (score 0):

1) When you have $\sqrt{z^2}$, technically we have $(e^{i\pi}z)^2$ by the branch cut, but obviously that cancels out to $z.$

2) Also the given assumption is valid here because of the expansion that has been chosen; the "circle" of radius of convergence for z in $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z}}$ contains $\infty$ (since the area of convergence is really outside the circle here).

Comment: How is the first line correct ?

Comment: The $\sqrt{z-z^2}$ term simplifies as mentioned earlier. As for $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z}}$, note that we can use the binomial theorem since it's $(1-\frac{1}{z})^{\frac{1}{2}}.$ Or maybe I'm answering the wrong thing..